# SharePoint site with with external sharing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, external-users

I'm creating a SharePoint site for our in-house users - they should be able to access the site, create folders and content but otherwise not be able to alter user permission or site design - they should also be able to create external anonymous sharing links links with people outside the company.
The Problem:
I cannot grant them the permission to create content on the site and be able to create and share anonymous links without giving them permission to change site design and user/site permissions. Is there a way to do this without giving them permission to change everything?
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the different level of permissions for groups and people.

Full Control - Has full control.

Design - Can view, add, update, delete, approve, and customize.

Edit - Can add, edit and delete lists; can view, add, update and delete list items and documents.

Contribute - Can view, add, update, and delete list items and documents.

Read - Can view pages and list items and download documents.

View Only - Can view pages, list items, and documents. Document types with server-side file handlers can be viewed in the browser but not downloaded.

If you set a group or person with the contribute permissions they should be able to create content and share that content on the site but not alter the site itself. They will only be able to share lists, documents and libraries if you want them to be able to share other things then they need higher permissions which would allow them to edit the site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With the contribute permission, will they be able to create external anonymous sharing link for a folder or list?

Comment: Yes they should be able to but what can be shared also depends on if the guest user is anonymous or just a external user. This site https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232 explains some of the fine details.